# Stopping a Handler Runnable after activity finishes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I have a method where I am making a TextView act as a "loading..." indicator.

I am doing this with a Runnable that updates the TextView every .5 seconds. Here is my function:

```
public void displayFlash() {
    animate = true;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(animate) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Running");
                        numFrames++;
                        switch (numFrames % 3) {
                        case 0:
                            loading.setText("Loading.");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            loading.setText("Loading..");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            loading.setText("Loading...");
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

The problem is, after this activity is finished (and destroyed), the thread continues running. I have a `System.out.println("running");` in the Runnable and this continues to log after this activity is finished. What do I need to do to kill this? I have tried `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);` and `Thread.interrupt();` with no luck.

Comment: You should **really, really** make your `Handler` static, or you will get in serious trouble. Check this excellent post to understand why: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari good read, thank you, will make it static :)

Comment: It does not make any difference if you make your Handler static or not because your Handler is not an anonymous class containing an implicit reference to your Activity. On the other hand, your Runnable contains an implicit reference to your Activity, so you must ensure you call handler.removeCallbacks() when the Activity stops to clear the Runnable reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void displayFlash() {
    animate = true;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable yourRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running");
            numFrames++;
            switch (numFrames % 3) {
                case 0:
                    loading.setText("Loading.");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    loading.setText("Loading..");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    loading.setText("Loading...");
                    break;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    }
    handler.post(yourRunnable);
}
```

Once you are done, call `handler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable);`

Comment: kotlin equivalent for this?

Answer (score 0):

How abbout using an AsyncTask? It's a class bonded with the activity that lets you override 4 methods, one doing background jobs and the other 3 communicating directly with the activity. For what I know, it automatically stops working after the Activity is dismissed, but, if I am being terribly wrong about this, you can always call the AsyncTask.cancel() method to stop it in Activity.onPause() method. It is not a conventional solution, for AsyncTask is usually used for short tasks, but could work. See Android Developers for documentation if you think the class can do the hack.

Comment: The problem with AsyncTask is getting it to run every X seconds...any input on that?

Comment: It is a bit trickier to do in an AsyncTask, actually. I guess my answer is not the best one in your situation :( sorry I couldn't help much.

Comment: It's too late now, but I discovered the sleep() method is static. Damn it XD